# Convenience Init For UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, initialization, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that I use in two places throughout my project.

Both `UICollectionViewCell`'s are the same apart from showing a `UIButton`. To reduce duplication of code I want to use the cell in both places but initialize one with a Boolean that determines if the button is shown or not.

I believe I need a convenience initializer to do this, however, I am getting the error;

> 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'

Code:

```
class MediaSelectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var withDeleteButton = false
    
    convenience init(showsDeleteButton: Bool) {
        self.init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Cells are reused, and call without your method. Instead, in cellForRow, add a didSet to `withDeleteButton` , to hide/show the button.

Comment: @Larme The cells are used in different parts of the app either all the cells will have the button or none will, so I think didSet is not really useful here. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @DavidHenry - you cannot initialize cells that way. You'll either need set the button hidden in `cellForItemAt`, or create two cell classes (subclassing a "base" cell would probably be the way to do it with that approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collectionview cell initialization doesn't have a methods called  `self.init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton)` that why you are getting an error message.

As said in the comment, cells are reuseable. If you register cell with storyboard ,  `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` initialization methods called ,  If you register cell programatically  `override init(frame: CGRect)` is called.

So I mean, If you use `dequeueReusableCell` you can not change the initialization method by hands.

I prefer to create a two classes to do what you want:

One for not showing button:

```
class MediaSelectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var withDeleteButton = false
   
      override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       // maybe adding constraint your bla bla
       
   }

   
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   func controlButton() -> Bool{
      if withDeleteButton{
         // show
         return true
     }else{
         // hide
         return false
     }
  }
 }
```

One for showing button :

```
class MediaSelectionShowButton : MediaSelectionCell{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.withDeleteButton = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And in your cell you can control and do what you want with it :

```
cell.controlButton()
```

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is wrong. The `MediaSelectionCell` class does have a `init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton)`. It's shown in the question. The error shown in the question is coming from trying to access `self.withDeleteButton` (with an implicit use of `self`) in the call to `self.init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton)`. The `init` method should do  `self.withDeleteButton = withDeleteButton` first, then call `super.init()`. But that also means `init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton)` can't be a convenience initializer.

Comment: Having said all of that, the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of this answer correctly point out the bigger issue. However, the `override init(frame)` code shown in this answer is wrong as well. It tries to act on the value of `withDeleteButton` before it could possibly have been set beyond the default value.

Comment: There is no designated initialization named self.init(showsDeleteButton: withDeleteButton) in the question? Even if it was, you're right when you say 2 to first comment.And thanks for second comment. You are right.Giving withDeleteButton to true in subclass and do something in baseclass init is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use a convenience initializer for table view or collection view cells because the table view/collection view creates them by calling the designated initializer.

You have to add a property to your custom class and set it up to honor that property.

Comment: This is only true if the cells are setup in a storyboard or if you register the cell with the table/collection view. I never do either of those and my custom cells all have custom `init` methods and they work just fine. However, there is no need for the custom `init` to be a convenience initializer. In the OP's case that was a mistake. It should have been a regular `init` that called an appropriate `super.init`.

Comment: If you don’t either register the cell class or the storyboard/nibfile with the table view, how does the dequeue method create new cells?

Comment: Or do you let it return nil and then call your custom initializer?

Comment: That's it - let `dequeue` return nil and then I call the custom init. Something along the lines of: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myId") as? MyCell ?? MyCell(reuseIdentifier: "myId", otherParams: otherValues)`